# Customizing health check URL for Amazon ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have been trying to create my own custom health check for my AWS ELB and have tried to follow the instructions on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/gs-ec2classic.html#ConfigureHealthCheck
Problem is when I "Edit health check" in my Load balancer configuration there is no mention of a "Path", Just Ping protocol, Ping port, Timeout, Interval, Healthy Threshold and Unhealthy Threshold.
I cannot find any way to have the ELB make a request to a specific URL.
What am I missing?

Comment: Path should only show up if your ping protocol is http.

Comment: Cheers Michael,  add your comment as an answer so I can accept it :) Been staring at it and rereadinig the doc over and over but never twigged that that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have ip address of EC2 instance-1 as 10.45.65.97 and EC2 instance-2 of 10.45.65.98 and have index.html page in `/var/www/html/index.html` (on both instances) and you are able access both pages from `http://10.45.65.97/index.html` and `http://10.45.65.98/index.html` you should give path as \index.html or if are able access you application just by putting `http://10.45.65.97` and `http://10.45.65.98` you should give path as .

Hope this helps.